# Obfuscating multiple related .NET assemblies with babel obfuscator

Tags: .net, obfuscation, babeljs

I have two assemblies, A and B, where A depends on B. I'm trying to obfuscate both of them together, i.e. in a way it doesn't break the app with the [babel obfuscator](http://code.google.com/p/babelobfuscator/).

Is there a way to do that? Apparently this obfuscator doesn't handle multiple assemblies.

If that's an issue, which other .NET obfuscator- that handles multiple assemblies- would you recommend?

Comment: I'm not sure when it happened, but Babel does have multiple assembly support now.

Answer (score 6):

You can use ILMerge to merge the assemblies and then babel to obfuscate the merged assembly.

ILMerge is a free Microsoft tool that can be downloaded at:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx

Comment: This is exactly how I handle the problem - works great, especially with the /internalize switch on ILMerge, which then lets Babel obfuscate the members that were public.

Comment: Also, nowadays Babel has the "Assembly Merging and Embedding" feature on some of its licenses. See all [features](http://www.babelfor.net/products/obfuscator)

Answer (score 1):

[**Dotfuscator**](http://dotfuscator-community-edition.software.informer.com/) Community edition. And here is its [MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227240.aspx)

If you want more power and ready to pay then go for [**XenoCode Post Build**.](http://www.xenocode.com/Products/Postbuild-for-NET/) or [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm). They also supply evaluation version.

Comment: In addition to the free community edition of Dotfuscator, which does handle multiple input assemblies, you can also request a free evaluation of the pro version of Dotfuscator with more obfuscation functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Is Linking them together an option? Dotfuscator allows you to Link Assemblies together and obfuscate the whole.

Check out [this article](http://www.preemptive.com/assembly-linking.html) if it is useful in your situation.

Comment: Dotfuscator also does not require linking them together, it can easily obfuscate multiple assemblies at one time (and rename referenced types between them consistently)

Answer (score 0):

You need a .NET obfuscator that will obfuscate multi assemblies: that is: when one member is renamed, it must be renamed in every assembly in the obfuscation project.
try [BitHelmet](http://www.bithelmet.com).
Regards